# How do I resolve the message "Validating WSFC quorum vote configuration - Action Required."

Tags: sql-server, windows-cluster, sql-server-2012

I have a 3 node AlwaysOn Availability Group on a 3 node WSFC using node majority. 2 nodes are setup as synchronous with automatic fail-over, the 3rd is setup as asynchronous with manual fail-over. When I try to fail-over using the GUI, I get a warning as shown in the screenshot. There is no warning or error if I fail-over with T-SQL.

Adding a file share to the quorum doesn't help. The only way I can resolve the warning is to remove the asynchronous sql instance from the 3rd node (it remains part of the WSFC). Either way, the AlwaysOn dashboard says quorum is OK. Am I missing something? Is this a bug in the GUI that I should just ignore?

[image: Fail Over Wizard]

Clicking "Action Required" gives the following error:

[image: The current WSFC cluster quorum vote configuration is not recommended for this availaiblity group.]

Comment: I have the exact same issue! If you managed to resolve this please post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same setup as you. For us, the fix was to apply the hotfix in [KB2494036](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2494036). Additional details and an outline of the issue and symptoms are available in [KB2761129](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2761129)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue. Check the status of FileStream on all the SQL Server instances and make sure it is uniform across all the nodes.

Comment: Kiran, it might be a good answer, if you explained your thinking and solvings.